# Nodejs Mysql Insert is adding backslashes to strings and fails

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm trying to do a simple sql insert using nodejs and express trying various formats I've found online, but this appears to be the accepted way. When I view the error it's adding extra backslashes to the query and failing.

The code:

```
console.log(request.body);

        var post = {uid: request.session.uid, title: request.body.title, created: request.body.createdAt};
        connection.query('INSERT INTO projects (uid, title, created) SET ? ', post, function (error, results, fields) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

The first body console.log:

```
{ title: 'aewgawegr', createdAt: '1574219119301' }
```

The error message:

```
  sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'SET `uid` = 1, `title` = \'aewgawegr\', `created` = \'1574219119301\'\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'INSERT INTO projects (uid, title, created) SET `uid` = 1, `title` = \'aewgawegr\', `created` = \'1574219119301\' ' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

You cannot combine the two usage syntax:

```
INSERt INTO `table` (column1, ...) VALUES (value1, ...
```

with

```
INSERT INTO `table` SET `column1`='value1', ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this instead of passing json object

```
"INSERT INTO projects (uid, title, created)  VALUES (1, 'Michelle', 'Blue Village 1')";
```

e.g in your case you can use string interpolation:

```
`INSERT INTO projects (uid, title, created)  VALUES ('${request.session.uid}', '${request.body.title}', '${request.body.createdAt}')`;
```